How to style Chart.js bar chart? I have an example of Chart
I need to create some bar chart.
This is a reference:
https://i.sstatic.net/Zj4G3BmS.png
This is what I have for now:
https://i.sstatic.net/pzPxKaZf.png
I marked my 3 questions on the reference with numbers:

How to add a custom block to the chart legend, like in the reference?
How to add such red blocks to the chart itself above the bars?
EDIT:
Here plugin for Chart.js
How to add padding between bars? - EDIT: Fix this. See comments in code section.

Regarding point 3 - I read about barPercentage and categoryPercentage and they did not help me.
Project stack:

Vue 3.4
Chart.js 4.4.2
Vue-chartjs 5.3.1

This is my component:
<template>
  <div
    class="bg-white rounded-md py-[12px] px-[20px] h-full flex items-center justify-center"
  >
    <Bar
      v-if="planFact"
      id="planfact-chart"
      :options="chartOptions"
      :data="(chartData as ChartData<'bar'>)"
      :plugins="[plugin]"
    />
    <div v-else>No data</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Bar, type ChartProps } from 'vue-chartjs';
import type { ChartData } from 'chart.js';
import { useChartStore } from '@/stores/chartStore';

const chartStore = useChartStore();
const { planFact, shortedPlanFactLabels } = storeToRefs(chartStore);

// https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/10388#issuecomment-1217363379
const plugin = {
  id: 'increase-legend-spacing',
  beforeInit(chart: any) {
    // Get reference to the original fit function
    const originalFit = chart.legend.fit;

    // Override the fit function
    chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
      // Call original function and bind scope in order to use `this` correctly inside it
      originalFit.bind(chart.legend)();
      // Change the height as suggested in another answers
      this.height += 15;
    };
  },
};

const chartOptions: ChartProps<'bar'>['options'] = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  layout: {
    padding: {
      top: -10,
    },
    autoPadding: true,
  },
  scales: {
    y: {
      ticks: {
        color: '#768295',
        stepSize: 50,
        font: {
          family: 'Noto Sans',
          size: 12,
        },
      },
      grid: {
        color: '#EBF0F4',
      },
      border: {
        color: '#EBF0F4',
      },
    },
    x: {
      ticks: {
        color: '#768295',
        font: {
          family: 'Noto Sans',
          size: 12,
        },
      },
      border: {
        color: '#EBF0F4',
      },
      grid: {
        color: '#EBF0F4',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      align: 'start',
      labels: {
        color: '#48546A',
        padding: 15,
        usePointStyle: true,
        pointStyle: 'circle',
        boxHeight: 5,
        font: {
          family: 'Noto Sans',
          size: 14,
        },
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
};

const chartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
  labels: shortedPlanFactLabels.value || [],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Fact',
      data: planFact.value?.fact || [],
      backgroundColor: ['#A594FF'],
      borderColor: '#A594FF',
      borderRadius: 3,
      // EDIT: need to remove barThickness and then barPercentage and categoryPercentage will work
      barThickness: 15,
      barPercentage: 1.0,
      categoryPercentage: 1.0,
      stack: 'bar',
    },
    {
      label: 'Plan',
      data: planFact.value?.plan || [],
      backgroundColor: ['#8792A3'],
      borderSkipped: 'bottom',
      borderRadius: 3,
      // EDIT: need to remove barThickness and then barPercentage and categoryPercentage will work
      barThickness: 15,
      barPercentage: 1.0,
      categoryPercentage: 1.0,
    },
  ],
};
</script>

For the third point, I tried using barPercentage and categoryPercentage, but it didn’t help me EDIT: see code section, for the rest I didn’t even find examples of something similar
